# Using erb within scss to render an model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to create a hero unit with a background image that is updateable in rails.

So far in my SCSS I have

```
//= depend_on_asset
$hero-image: '<%= SiteSetting.first.landing_background.url %>';
```

this works but unfortunately when the image is changed the assets don't recompile like they should.

How can I get my assets to recompile when `landing_background` is updated?

I'm using this for a hero unit from [Refills](http://refills.bourbon.io/) so I'm reluctant to change it overly to an image tag

Comment: Why are you using a model attribute in css? Why can't you use image_tag ?

Comment: Because its a variable from refills hero unit, I don't want to break the code they provide to that extent for a prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have your asset's pipeline turned off and just compile the scss sources with each request, this won't work, it will work once and then whenever you change that image, you'd have to recompile the sass file again for the change to take effect.

I'd move this functionality to inline css within the views; the asset pipeline is meant for the rarely dynamic content hence its precompiled and no processing happens beyond that during runtime.